# Difficulties adding a date in auction

Tags: jquery

Good morning !

I have a simple problem with this part of jquery code , when I try to add the date in jquery I am using this.

```
$('.subastas').append("<div class='hola'>"+tiempo(data.subastas[i].data_final)+"</div>");
```

However , if i put the date with the following form I can show the time correctly.

```
$('.subastas').append("<div class='hola'>"+tiempo('2015/12/12')+"</div>");
```

Which is the difference betweent two codes ? I think is the same. The complete code I leave below.

```
$.ajax({
                url:   'en/listarsubastas',
                type:  'get',
                success:  function (data) {
                    for(var i=0;i<=data.subastas.length;i++){
                        console.log(data.subastas[i].data_final);
                        $('.subastas').append("<div class='hola'>"+tiempo(prueba)+"</div>");
                    }
                }
        });
```

The time function()

```
function tiempo(tiempo){
        $('.hola').countdown(tiempo, function(event) {
            $(this).html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
        });
    }
```

My console

[image]

Comment: What is are the results? and what is shown in the console?

Comment: Could you post the tiempo() function as well?

Comment: When is `prueba` being set? Are there any errors on the JS console?

Comment: I don' have any errors in the Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try parse the result before iterate over like :

```
success:  function (data) {
  var data = $.parseJSON( data );
  for(var i=0;i<=data.subastas.length;i++){...}
}
```

Comment: What i see the difference is the data having `-` as a separator. Ever try like `tiempo('2015-12-12')`

Answer (score 0):

I think "data.subastas[i].data_final" Date type, so you should be convert Date to string before send to function "tiempo".

Comment: I put the tiem function , @P.Kriengkri

Comment: Could you show the result of "data.subastas[i].data_final", please ? @jcsa

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
$('.subastas').append("<div class='hola'>"+tiempo(data.subastas[i].data_final.replace(/-/g, '/'))+"</div>");
```